# drawing a line from a UIViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, uiviewcontroller

I have a UIViewController which has a UIImageView. I wanted to draw a line on top of the UIImageView. I know that in order to do this I have to override the drawRect in a UIView. Is there an alternative to this?

Comment: I answered below, but why would you not want to override drawRect?

Comment: because it would be annoying to just have a UIImage class with a drawRect on it?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor redColor].CGColor);
CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 1.0f);
CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 0, 0); 
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, view.frame.size.width, view.frame.size.height);
CGContextStrokePath(context);
```

Comment: @adit, I don't know what is your imageview name. It's just a common example.

Answer (score 0):

While overriding drawRect may be the best solution, there are always alternatives.

If the line is horizontal or vertical, you could create a UIView with the frame of the line you need and set its background color.

You could overlay an image of the line, rotated/resized as needed.